# How to read/parse individual transform style values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webkit, css, transform

Webkit's blog post from last year on [3D transforms](http://webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) explains the various transform 'functions' that can be used in the -webkit-transform property. For example:

```
#myDiv {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateY(7deg) translateZ(-1px);
}
```

My question: how do you access individual values in JavaScript? When you read the webkitTransform property of the element, you just get a matrix3d() function with 16 values in it, like this...

```
matrix3d(0.958684, 0.000000, .....)
```

Is there a way to just read the value of an individual transform thing, like rotateY()? Or do I have to read it from the matrix3d() string, and how?

Answer (score 11):

```
// Suppose the transformed element is called "cover".
var element = document.getElementById('cover');
computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null); // "null" means this is not a pesudo style.
// You can retrieve the CSS3 matrix string by the following method.
var matrix = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('transform')
    || computedStyle.getPropertyValue('-moz-transform')
    || computedStyle.getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform')
    || computedStyle.getPropertyValue('-ms-transform')
    || computedStyle.getPropertyValue('-o-transform');

// Parse this string to obtain different attributes of the matrix.
// This regexp matches anything looks like this: anything(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
// Hence it matches both matrix strings:
// 2d: matrix(1,2,3,4,5,6)
// 3d: matrix3d(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
var matrixPattern = /^\w*\((((\d+)|(\d*\.\d+)),\s*)*((\d+)|(\d*\.\d+))\)/i;
var matrixValue = [];
if (matrixPattern.test(matrix)) { // When it satisfy the pattern.
    var matrixCopy = matrix.replace(/^\w*\(/, '').replace(')', '');
    console.log(matrixCopy);
    matrixValue = matrixCopy.split(/\s*,\s*/);
}
```

Hope this helps!
Note that I did not use another library except plain DOM API and native Javascript RegExp function. Hence, this should work universally cross browsers and application.

Comment: Although this splits each matrix value into an array, the values do not represent the CSS transform properties and therefore, does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: **warning** this will cause bugs with negative numbers. Use `let matrixPattern = /^\w*\((-?((\d+)|(\d*\.\d+)),\s*)*(-?(\d+)|(\d*\.\d+))\)/i` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Old but interesting question and no previous response has attempted to answer it.

Unfortunately there's no two-liner solution for the general case and we don't know about what variety of transform steps (rotate, translate etc.) need to be reverse engineered; the fewer the easier.

In recent webkit based browsers, one can simply query the previously assigned property:

```
var element = document.querySelector('div.slipping');
element.style.webkitTransform 
  -> "translate(-464px, 0px)"
```

Let's continue with the assumption that the computed style needs to be used. The need arises, for example, if the element is in the middle of a CSS transition or CSS animation, i.e. the current transformation is not one that was set directly.

The matrix descriptor string returned by getComputedStyle can indeed be parsed via a regex, but not all versions above are reliable, and they're too opaque. A straightforward way to break down the string, unless it's in a very tight loop to warrant a single-pass regex, is this:

```
var matrixString = window.getComputedStyle(element).webkitTransform;
var matrix = matrixString
             .split('(')[1]
             .split(')')[0]
             .split(',')
             .map(parseFloat);
```

But another way is to simply use this, which wasn't mentioned before:

```
var cssMatrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(matrixString);
```

The benefit of the latter approach is that you get back a 4x4 matrix as well, which is the standard representation for [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), and the drawback is that it's of course WebKit specific. Should you continue to work with the tuple of six values as in the question, it's defined [in this part of the CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#mathematical-description).

Then the transform, e.g. rotation needs to be reverse engineered. There can be many simple transforms directly supported by CSS, e.g. translate, scale, rotate, skew, and perspective. If only one of them is applied, then you just need to revert the process of [computing the transform matrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#mathematical-description).

An alternative is to find or translate code which does this for you in JS, e.g. [the same document](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#interpolation-of-3d-matrices) or [Section 7.1 of the CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-2d-transforms-20111215/) contains such annotated algorithms. The benefit is that the [unmatrix](http://pythonhackers.com/p/jkroso/unmatrix) approach is able to, with some limitations, return the 'atomic' transforms even if more than one of these (translate, rotate etc.) is applied. Since it's not possible to guarantee the successful reverse engineering of the transform steps for the general case, it's useful to think about what types of transforms are possibly applied, and whether degenerate or other troublesome cases have been avoided. I.e. you need to build the solution as you see fit for your problem.

Specifically, the matrix versions of all 2D CSS transforms are [documented here as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#mathematical-description), below the meaning of the six values in the CSS 2D transform vector.

Another caveat is that there are other things that influence the visual outcome in terms of geometric operations, for example, [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Answer (score 4):

### Extract *key/value* pairs from a complex transform string:

using [regex.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches) method

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).  Note that the `lastIndex` property will not be reset when searching a different string, it will start its search at its existing `lastIndex`.

```js
function parseComplexStyleProperty( str ){
   var regex = /(\w+)\((.+?)\)/g, transform = {}, match;

   while( match = regex.exec(str) )
       transform[match[1]] = transform[match[1]] 
           ? transform[match[1]].concat([match[2]])
           : [match[2]]
  
   return transform
}


/// USAGE: ///////////////////////////////////////

var dummyString = "translateX(-50%) translateX(100px) scale(1.2)",
    transformObj = parseComplexStyleProperty(dummyString);

console.log(transformObj)
```

Note - mind that this is also a valid CSS transform value:

```
translateX(-50%) translateX(100px);
```

---

### More Complex Cases:

```js
function parseTransform(s){ 
  var keys = ['matrix3d', 'matrix', 'perspective', 'rotate3d', 'rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ', 'rotate', 'translate3d', 'translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ', 'translate', 'scale3d', 'scaleX', 'scaleY', 'scaleZ', 'scale', 'skewX', 'skewY',  'skew'];

  return (s+'    ').replace(  new RegExp( '\\b' + keys.join('|') + '\\b','gi'), m => '    ' +m)
  .split(')    ').reduce((acc, p) => {
    p = p.trim()

    var name = p.slice(0, p.indexOf('(')),
        value = p.slice(p.indexOf('(') + 1, 999)

    if(!p) return acc
   
    if( acc[name] ) 
      acc[name].push(value)
    else 
      acc[name] = [value]

    return acc
  }, {})
}


console.log(
parseTransform('scale(1.2 0.5) rotate(var(--c1) var(--c2)) translateX(-50%) translateX(100px)')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, as syockit says, iterating through the stylesheets is the only way to go, you can use `webkitMatchesSelector` to discover rules which match your element:

```
var theRules = new Array();
var theStylesheet = document.styleSheets;
if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
        theRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules)
        theRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules

var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");

for (var i=0; i < theRules.length; i++) {
    if (elem.webkitMatchesSelector(theRules[i].selectorText)) {
        var theStyles = theRules[i].style;
        var j = theStyles.cssText.indexOf('-webkit-transform:');
        if (j>-1) {
            var s = theStyles.cssText.substring(j,theStyles.cssText.length).indexOf(';'); 
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=theStyles.cssText.substring(j+18,s);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes markup something like this, I added some extra rules and values to make sure I was pulling out the right values.  If you have more than one stylesheet then you need to adjust the first part to iterate through all the stylesheets too, and you'll probably have to deal with specificity if your `-webkit-transform` appears in more than one rule:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Get style</title>
    <style>
    div {
        margin: 2em;
        padding: 2em;
    }
    #myDiv {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateY(7deg) translateZ(-1px);
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        Just testing.
    </div>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added your code on fiddle and cannot get any reading http://jsfiddle.net/ypf2wv4g/9/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue this morning. It appears that JavaScript can't read an element's `style.webkitTransform` property until it's been explicitly set in the element's `style` attribute (either inline in the HTML or procedurally via JavaScript). As kludgy as this sounds, if you need JS to be able to read CSS transform properties, you might be better off defining their initial values with JavaScript when the DOM is ready.

Example, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.transform').css('webkitTransform', 'translateX(0)');
});
```

From this point forward, you'll be able to read the element's transform string and parse through it for the needed values.

Answer (score 1):

This [link from Apple Dev Reference](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/internetweb/conceptual/safarivisualeffectsprogguide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH5-SW21) might shed more light on the subject:

> The webkitTransform property is a
>   string representation of a list of
>   transform operations. Usually this
>   list contains a single matrix
>   transform operation. For 3D
>   transforms, the value is
>   "matrix3d(...)" with the 16 values of
>   the 4x4 homogeneous matrix between the
>   parentheses. For 2D transforms, the
>   value is a "matrix(...)" string
>   containing the 6 vector values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only get the final matrix value from the computed style, you might have to check the element's inline style or stylesheet rules. If `element.style.webkitTransform` gives you nothing, you might to iterate through the document's stylesheets, and see which one matches your element. Then you can regex the `webkitTransform` property to get/set the value.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use regex to get a map of property-value:**

*if variable transformstyle contains the style value*

```
  //get all transform declarations
 (transformstyle.match(/([\w]+)\(([^\)]+)\)/g)||[]) 
      //make pairs of prop and value         
     .map(function(it){return it.replace(/\)$/,"").split(/\(/)})
     //convert to key-value map/object         
     .reduce(function(m,it){return m[it[0]]=it[1],m},{})
```

*for:*

```
var transformstyle="-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateY(7deg) translateZ(-1px)"
```

*you would get:*

```
{scale: "1.1", rotateY: "7deg", translateZ: "-1px"}
```

Comment: Its surprising that such an awesome feature doesn't have a more powerful javascript API. Really, individual values needs to be parsed using regex? Blech.

Comment: No ! Standard js getComputedStyle return a matrix/matrix3d.
So, you have to parse and compute matrix datas to get css transformations back.

Comment: Although this splits each matrix value into an array, the values do not represent the CSS transform properties and therefore, does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: This was a pretty good solve for me, regardless of the original question. I was setting the initial transform style with javascript, so running it through this regex gave me everything split out so I could preserve the initial values and only modify the new values through a subsequent style declaration, like  el.style.transform = `scale(${transformstyle.scale}) translateZ(newZ)`

Answer (score 0):

Just because I didn´t see any working Javascript one Line solutions to convert the matrix code, here is mine. Quick and easy:

First get all the transform Values in a matrix:

```
var yourDivsCssValues= window.getComputedStyle(yourDiv, null);
transformValues = testDivCSS.getPropertyValue('transform');
```

To extract transform-y as an Integer:

```
var transformValueY = parseInt((yourVariable1.replace (/,/g, "")).split(" ")[5]);
```

To extract transform-x as an Integer:

```
var transformValuetX = parseInt((yourVariable2.replace (/,/g, "")).split(" ")[4]);
```

Accessing the rotation value is quite difficult, but there is a good guide, if you want to do it:
https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the complete transformation, you can indeed use `getComputedStyle(element).transform`.

But anyway, just use [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix/DOMMatrix) constructor: `new DOMMatrix(element.style.transform)`. And you're done.