# Regular Expression (Regex) on CSS3 Transform String

Tags: javascript, regex, css, replace, webkit-transform

Given a string `"translateX(-50%) scale(1.2)"` with N transform functions

1) How can I match the names `["translateX", "scale"]`?

2) How can I match the values `["-50%", "1.2"]`?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read individual '-webkit-transform' values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432446/how-to-read-individual-webkit-transform-values-in-javascript)

Comment: The question is very obvious, though not explicit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely must use regular expression to do this, you can use the [`exec()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) method in a loop, pushing the match result of the captured group(s) to the desired arrays of choice.

```
var str = 'translateX(-50%) scale(1.2)'
var re  = /(\w+)\(([^)]*)\)/g, 
names = [], vals = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  names.push(m[1]), vals.push(m[2]);
}

console.log(names) //=> [ 'translateX', 'scale' ] 
console.log(vals)  //=> [ '-50%', '1.2' ]
```

The regular expression uses two capture groups, the first matches/captures word characters only, the second uses negation which will match any character except `)` "zero or more" times.

Comment: can you explain whats going on?

Comment: the capture groups, how you're excluding parens, using commas instead of semicolons etc. is there any good site to really learn regex well? i feel like it's an incredibly valuable tool especially for natural language processing

Comment: If you're new to regular expressions, I would start [**here**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `(\w+)\((.+?)\)`:

- `(\w+)`: Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1

  - `\w+`: Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)

    - `+`: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\(`: Match the character “(” literally
- `(.+?)`: Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2

  - `.+?`: Match any single character that is not a line break character

    - `+?`: Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `\)`: Match the character “)” literally

```js
var str = "translateX(-50%) scale(1.2)",
    regex = /(\w+)\((.+?)\)/g,
    match, names = [], values = [];
while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    names.push(match[1]);
    values.push(match[2]);
}
```

Comment: @hwnd Oh, you beat me by 6 seconds :) Well, there is the difference between `.+?` and `[^)]*`.

Comment: could this not match `translateX(`-50%) scale(1.2`)`

Comment: @neaumusic But that is not a valid [<transform-list>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#typedef-transform-list)

Comment: sorry, updated it. so it will never keep looking once the closing paren is found?

Comment: @neaumusic Yes, it needs a closing parenthesis. And `translateX(-50%) scale(1.2)` works: http://jsfiddle.net/f9nyv4nd/

Comment: ah "as few times as possible"