# CSS Transform in World/Screen Space

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have two nested elements, lets say:

```
<div id="outside">
    <div id="inside">Foo</div>
</div>
```

and I apply a rotation to the outside element, lets say rotated clockwise by 45 degrees:

```
<div id="outside" style="transform: rotateZ(-45deg);">
    <div id="inside">Foo</div>
</div>
```

and I now want to translate the inside div down the screen a bit.

```
<div id="outside" style="transform: rotateZ(-45deg);">
    <div id="inside" style="transform: translateY(100px);">Foo</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/du2w91vw/8/

Oh no! it's inherited its parents transform (which I actually want) and moved it down at a 45 degree angle. How then do I move it down vertically, relative to the screen (i.e. a world-space translation)?

now, I could store all its parent transforms and calculate it myself, and work out the correct translation, but then I might as well just have a completely flat dom hierarchy and do it all myself. I want to make use of the implicitly inherited transforms!

**tl;dr: Is there a way to get an element's world transform without looking up the entire DOM tree for transforms, or storing all parent transforms in memory?**

Note: My requirement is that I cannot move the outer div.

Edit: I've just found out about getComputedStyle, which gives me a matrix back. Bit of a messy solution (do browsers always return the same format?) but I might be able figure it out with this.

```
var t = getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('transform')
// e.g. t = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -333, -26)"
```

Edit edit: getComputedStyle is ugly. Ugh, why is there no good solution for this. [How to read individual transform values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432446/how-to-read-individual-webkit-transform-values-in-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by "move it relative to the screen?" What are you trying to accomplish with the 200px transform?

Comment: Simply move the element down the screen vertically, not on a 45 degree angle.

Comment: I get what you want. Have you considered applying the translation on `.outside` instead of `.inside`? Or even changing the transform origin to -200px would do.

Comment: I have Derek, but this does not solve the general case! Imagine I have an entire graph full of nodes and I only want to move the leaves. Moving the parent nodes will move everything!

Comment: @BrendanAnnable If you want precise locations and less restrictions, you might want to try to draw on a canvas instead.

Comment: I love your creative solutions Derek! Unfortunately these do not satisfy my requirements! :) If it's not possible, then I'll live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear on what your actual code looks like, but in the case where you want to both rotate and translate an object down a page you may want to consider moving the object before the rotation.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outside">
    <div id="inside">Fooooooooooooo</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#inside{
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#outside{
    -ms-transform: translateY(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
    transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du2w91vw/)

Let me know if your page structure does not work with this solution.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the parent is not allowed to move!